# Почему настроенный виртуальный хост вместо сайта отображает содержание директории на уровень выше?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, virtualbox

Есть виртуалка Ubuntu 14.04 в VirtualBox. Настроил хост для проекта на Silex, настройки базовые совсем. Но вначале была проблема с тем, что при открытии адреса открывалась дефолтная страница апача, а сейчас - при открытии адреса открывается листинг директории на уровень выше (/var/www, а сайт в /var/www/site.local). При открытии в этом листинге "папки" с проектом - получается урл вида site.local/site.local и silex выбрасывает 404 ошибку. В чем может быть причина?

UPD: конфиг апача [здесь](https://glot.io/snippets/e5tn89bu0z)

Comment: А адрес какой открываете? site.local? В конфиге у вас просто karusel.local упомянут. И апач после настройки конфига перезагружали?

Comment: Нет, сайт - karusel.local. Перезагружал, конечно.

Comment: *при открытии адреса открывалась дефолтная страница апача* — рискну предположить, что в попытке это исправить вы и привели конфигурацию сервера к текущему состоянию. покажите, пожалуйста, содержимое **всех** файлов, симлинки на которые, или они сами, располагаются в каталоге `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: [Здесь](https://glot.io/snippets/e5tu8lkmvf). Тестовый хост создал потом - на нем та же проблема. Сервер новый, недавно развернутый, поэтому на нем нету ничего, и так же нету ничего специфичного.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было исправить в конфиге NameVirtualHost karusel.local:80, < VirtualHost karusel.local:80 >, а  NameVirtualHost *:80 и аналогично далее.